# Hover color overlay that affects multiple elements

Tags: html, css

Heres where I'm at:
http://codepen.io/qdarkness/pen/FyIJh

Ideally, how I imagine it at least, is when a user hovers over the `<a>` that the `<div>`'s "img-holder" and "tag" both have a transition to color, with the "img-holder" showing a "+" in the middle.

I'm suspecting the fact that I have the `<img>` inside the `<div>` that it is not working properly, but I am using that div to constrain the `img` width and height.

I'd prefer not to add additional divs, is this possible by just apply a class, like i attempted to, to the `<div>`?

HTML:

```
<li class="b c d">
  <a href="" class="link">
    <div class="img-holder overlay"><img src="img/test.jpg"></div>
    <div class="tag overlay">
      <h3>test</h3>
      <h4>test</h4>
    </div>
  </a>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
.img-holder {
  width: 235px;
  height: 195px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tag {
  clear:both;
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  width: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  -moz-transition: 1s;
  -ms-transition: 1s;
  -o-transition: 1s;
  transition: 1s;
}

a:hover .overlay {
  background: #909090;
  z-index: 301;
}
```

Comment: what exactly are you asking? you can just write a new rule for every child element of a:hover like you are with a:hover .overlay { etc...

Comment: Not totally clear on the goal. You want to overlay a color over the entire holder on hover? As in, the image would be covered by grey?

Comment: Sorry, I would like it to have this effect: http://codepen.io/vladal/pen/iuoxg and to show how it would overall work: http://richard-carpenter.co.uk/. As you can see with the last link, when u hover over any part, it applies color to both sections.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I THINK I have an understanding of what you want to do...

I've forked your Codepen sketch: http://cdpn.io/uzfrk

Main points are to position the overlay `absolute` over your image (relative to .link), and then transition `opacity` to have it appear.

`<old example removed>`

---

**UPDATED:** fresh sketch with cleaned up markup and styling. Simple example for your purposes.
Codepen sketch here: http://cdpn.io/zhBcA

The main point is the [direct child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) to target elements related to your container.

```
figure:hover > figcaption {
  background: #ccc;
}

figure:hover > .overlay {
  opacity: 0.85;
}
```

Let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I explained it correctly. Basically what I have in there is good. However I'm having trouble putting an grey covered overlay with a white plus in the middle, OVER the IMG. Keeping the bottom transition in tact.

Comment: Ha, well OK then. Ignore this answer for now :)

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for, unfortunately I don't think this solution will work because I need those <div>s and <li>s and the <a> needs to encompass the entire section so a modal function will work.

Comment: Sure, I applied to a generic solution rather than your specific. Glad I at least finally understood :)

Answer (score 0):

Could this be what you want? It's just a simple approach.

**UPDATE:**

Covering text area now.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tlKCJ

Comment: I think he wants the overlay to appear as well as having the bottom `.tag` portion to change background color

Comment: I've modified the code the apply overlay on the text contents too